# Can you pass an element to a function within the template in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to calculate and set an element's `max-height` style programmatically based on the number of children it has. I have to do this on four separate elements, each with a different number of children, so I can't just create a single computed property. I already have the logic to calculate the `max-height` in the function, but I'm unable to pass an element from the template into a function.

I've tried the following solutions with no luck:

1. `<div ref="div1" :style="{ maxHeight: getMaxHeight($refs.div1) }"></div>`
   This didn't work because `$refs` is not yet defined at the time I'm passing it into the function.
2. Trying to pass `this` or `$event.target` to `getMaxHeight()`. This didn't work either because `this` doesn't refer to the current element, and there was no event since I'm not in a `v-on` event handler.

The only other solution I can think of is creating four computed properties that each call `getMaxHeight()` with the `$ref`, but if I can handle it from a single function called with different params, it would be easier to maintain. If possible, I would like to pass the element itself from the template. Does anyone know of a way to do this, or a more elegant approach to solving this problem?

Comment: Think about custom directive - you can simply access bound element within. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html

Answer (score 2):

I ended up creating a directive like was suggested. It tries to expand/compress when:

- It's clicked
- Its classes change
- The element or its children update

---

Vue component:

```
<button @click="toggleAccordion($event.currentTarget.nextElementSibling)"></button>
<div @click="toggleAccordion($event.currentTarget)" v-accordion-toggle>
    <myComponent v-for="data in dataList" :data="data"></myComponent>
</div>
```

.....

```
private toggleAccordion(elem: HTMLElement): void {
    elem.classList.toggle("expanded");
}
```

---

Directive: `Accordion.ts`

```
const expandable = (el: HTMLElement) => el.style.maxHeight = (el.classList.contains("expanded") ?
    [...el.children].map(c => c.scrollHeight).reduce((h1, h2) => h1 + h2) : "0") + "px";

Vue.directive("accordion-toggle", {
    bind: (el: HTMLElement, binding: any, vnode: any) => {
        el.onclick = ($event: any) => {
            expandable($event.currentTarget) ; // When the element is clicked
        };

        // If the classes on the elem change, like another button adding .expanded class
        const observer = new MutationObserver(() => expandable(el));        
        observer.observe(el, {
            attributes: true,
            attributeFilter: ["class"],
        });
    },
    componentUpdated: (el: HTMLElement) => {
        expandable(el); // When the component (or its children) update
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A cheap trick I learned with Vue is that if you require anything in the template that isnt loaded when the template is mounted is to just put a template with a v-if on it:

```
<template v-if="$refs">
   <div ref="div1" :style="{ maxHeight: getMaxHeight($refs.div1) }"></div>
</template>
```

around it. This might look dirty at first, but the thing is, it does the job without loads of extra code and time spend and prevents the errors.

Also, a small improvement in code length on your `expandable`-function:

```
const expandable = el => el.style.maxHeight = 
    ( el.classList.contains('expanded') ?  
        el.children.map(c=>c.scrollHeight).reduce((h1,h2)=>h1+h2)
        : 0 ) + 'px';
```

Comment: I do like using `v-if` when things could be null/undefined. That's something I do use pretty often, but I think the directive approach here is a better solution since I'm gonna try to use it in a few spots throughout the project. I like your `expandable` code better though, I'll implement it like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Making a custom directive that operates directly on the div element would probably be your best shot. You could create a directive component like:

```
export default {
  name: 'maxheight',
  bind(el) {
    const numberOfChildren = el.children.length;

    // rest of your max height logic here

    el.style.maxHeight = '100px';
  }
}
```

Then just make sure to import the directive in the file you plan on using it, and add it to your div element:

```
<div ref="div1" maxheight></div>
```